# Display block not letting me to click on anchor tag

Tags: html, css

When I click on the anchor tag (inside `SubLinklist`) again after the first setting `display: none` and `display: block` the anchor tag is no longer working. And the anchor tag does not go to that link. I tried but can't figure it out. Eagerly Need Help. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="Linklist">
    <li class="Linklist__Item" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a href="/pages/collaborations-1" class="Link Link--secondary left">COLLABORATIONS</a>
        <a href="#hide" id="hide" class="hide" tabindex="1">➕</a>
        <a href="#show" id="show" class="show" tabindex="2">➖</a>

        <ul class="SubLinklist" id="list">
            <li class="Linklist__SubItem">
                <a href="/pages/collaborations" class="Link Link--secondary">ALISA KARIN</a>
            </li>
            <li class="Linklist__SubItem">
                <a href="/pages/jeffrey-campbell-x-jade-venturi" class="Link Link--secondary">JEFFREY CAMPBELL</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="Linklist__Item">
        <a href="/pages/music" class="Link Link--secondary left">PLAYLISTS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Linklist__Item">
        <a href="/blogs/news" class="Link Link--secondary left">PRESS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Linklist__Item">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jadeventuri_/" class="Link Link--secondary left">INSTAGRAM</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
  .SubLinklist {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .Linklist__SubItem {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .hide, .show {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
  #list, .show, .hide:focus {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .hide:focus + .show,
  .hide:focus ~ #list {
    display: block!important;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```css
.SubLinklist {
        list-style: none;
      }
      .Linklist__SubItem {
        padding-top: 10px;
      }
      .hide, .show {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 30px;
      }
      #list, .show, .hide:focus {
        display: none!important;
      }
      .hide:focus + .show,
      .hide:focus ~ #list {
        display: block!important;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<ul class="Linklist">
        <li class="Linklist__Item" aria-haspopup="true">
            <a href="/pages/collaborations-1" class="Link Link--secondary left">COLLABORATIONS</a>
            <a href="#hide" id="hide" class="hide" tabindex="1">➕</a>
            <a href="#show" id="show" class="show" tabindex="2">➖</a>
    
            <ul class="SubLinklist" id="list">
                <li class="Linklist__SubItem">
                    <a href="/pages/collaborations" class="Link Link--secondary">ALISA KARIN</a>
                </li>
                <li class="Linklist__SubItem">
                    <a href="/pages/jeffrey-campbell-x-jade-venturi" class="Link Link--secondary">JEFFREY CAMPBELL</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="Linklist__Item">
            <a href="/pages/music" class="Link Link--secondary left">PLAYLISTS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="Linklist__Item">
            <a href="/blogs/news" class="Link Link--secondary left">PRESS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="Linklist__Item">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jadeventuri_/" class="Link Link--secondary left">INSTAGRAM</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: this would be a great opportunity to try out the javascript "snippet" functionality in stack overflow : https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @DanielFarrell Can you please give me a guideline to do this with js?

Comment: "When I click on the anchor tag again..." Which of the 8 anchor tags?

Comment: Developers that are ready to help "eagerly need help" to understand what the problem is about.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis Extremely sorry for not mentioning the tag specifically. I just edited my question. It's anchor tag inside `SubLinklist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the `:focus` pseudo-class in combination with `display: none` on the same element. If an element has focus and gets hidden, then it looses the focus again - thus, the selector using `:focus` does not match anymore.

You could use a hidden checkbox for keeping the expansion state for each node. Then, simply wrap the "+" and "-" icons with a `label` element referencing the checkbox via its `for` attribute. With the checkout it is possible to use the `:checked` pseudo-class in combination with the sibling selector `~` to implement the desired behavior.

**Possible solution:**

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.SubLinklist {
  list-style: none;
}

.Linklist__SubItem {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.hide,
.show {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 90px;
}

.SubLinklist {
  display: none;
}

.state-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.state-checkbox ~ .show {
  display: block;
}

.state-checkbox ~ .hide {
  display: none;
}

.state-checkbox:checked ~ .show {
  display: none;
}

.state-checkbox:checked ~ .hide {
  display: block;
}

.state-checkbox:checked ~ .SubLinklist {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="Linklist">
    <li class="Linklist__Item" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a href="/pages/collaborations-1" class="Link Link--secondary left">COLLABORATIONS</a>
        <input id="cb-show-menu" type="checkbox" class="state-checkbox">

        <label for="cb-show-menu" class="hide" tabindex="1">
          <div tabindex="1">➖</div>
        </label>

        <label for="cb-show-menu" class="show" tabindex="2">
          <div tabindex="2">➕</div>
        </label>            
        
        <ul class="SubLinklist" id="list">
            <li class="Linklist__SubItem">
                <a href="/pages/collaborations" class="Link Link--secondary">
                  ALISA KARIN
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="Linklist__SubItem">
                <a href="/pages/jeffrey-campbell-x-jade-venturi" class="Link Link--secondary">
                    JEFFREY CAMPBELL
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="Linklist__Item">
        <a href="/pages/music" class="Link Link--secondary left">PLAYLISTS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Linklist__Item">
        <a href="/blogs/news" class="Link Link--secondary left">PRESS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="Linklist__Item">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jadeventuri_/" class="Link Link--secondary left">
            INSTAGRAM
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this your desired result? I removed `!important` and removed `.hide:focus` from `display: none;`. I think the `display: none` and `display: block` were sort of clashing into each other.

```css
    .SubLinklist {
     list-style: none;
}
 .Linklist__SubItem {
     padding-top: 10px;
}
 .hide, .show {
     float: right;
     margin-right: 30px;
}
 #list, .show {
     display: none;
}
 .hide:focus + .show, .hide:focus ~ #list {
     display: block;
     padding-left: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="Linklist">
   <li class="Linklist__Item" aria-haspopup="true">
      <a href="/pages/collaborations-1" class="Link Link--secondary left">COLLABORATIONS</a>
      <a href="#hide" id="hide" class="hide" tabindex="1">➕</a>
      <a href="#show" id="show" class="show" tabindex="2">➖</a>
      <ul class="SubLinklist" id="list">
         <li class="Linklist__SubItem">
            <a href="/pages/collaborations" class="Link Link--secondary">ALISA KARIN</a>
         </li>
         <li class="Linklist__SubItem">
            <a href="/pages/jeffrey-campbell-x-jade-venturi" class="Link Link--secondary">JEFFREY CAMPBELL</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="Linklist__Item">
      <a href="/pages/music" class="Link Link--secondary left">PLAYLISTS</a>
   </li>
   <li class="Linklist__Item">
      <a href="/blogs/news" class="Link Link--secondary left">PRESS</a>
   </li>
   <li class="Linklist__Item">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jadeventuri_/" class="Link Link--secondary left">INSTAGRAM</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```